# Mobile menu for bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a slightly different form of navigation.  The structure is like so

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left vertical-center" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#hero"><span>H</span><span>O</span><span>M</span><span>E</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio"><span>W</span><span>O</span><span>R</span><span>K</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about"><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>O</span><span>U</span><span>T</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact"><span>C</span><span>O</span><span>N</span><span>T</span><span>A</span><span>C</span><span>T</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And with the CSS I display the menu vertically down the side of the page.  I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jy1a426/5/) to demonstrate.

My question relates to how I can get this to switch to the standard bootstrap mobile menu on mobile devices?

Thanks

Comment: please clarify more , what do you mean by the standard bootstrap mobile menu on mobile devices ?

Comment: Use a media query to remove all the custom styling?

Comment: So when you resize this page https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ you will see that it changes to a mobile menu.  This is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
[Pnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lz4LTVqS5es62O9hYQha?p=preview)

```
     <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-left vertical-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapsed">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCollapsed">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#hero"><span>H</span><span>O</span><span>M</span><span>E</span></a></li>
                      <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio"><span>W</span><span>O</span><span>R</span><span>K</span></a></li>
                      <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about"><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>O</span><span>U</span><span>T</span></a></li>
                      <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact"><span>C</span><span>O</span><span>N</span><span>T</span><span>A</span><span>C</span><span>T</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Added a button for when the menu is collapsed, which will show up when the navbar breakpoint is reached. The list items are then added under this button.

I use media queries to switch up the style and removing the vertical alignment of the navbar.